# Can't get access to QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I'm new to QT and I've watched some tutorials about how to create a widget app. In most of them, I had to modify label text using:

```
ui->label->setText("smthg");
```

I've tried the same thing with QTextEdit and can't seem have access to it.

Tried `ui->help_plz`, says **"no member named "textEdit" in UI::MainWindow".**

How can I access QTextEdit and copy text from it?

Code:
main window.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>550</width>
    <height>368</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>210</y>
      <width>114</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="succ">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>59</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="help_plz">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>113</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>550</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwidow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->succ->setText("yeah");
    ui->help_plz //no member named "help_plz" in UI::MainWindow
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: where is the textEdit in your main window ui class?

Comment: Check the generated `.h` file for your `.ui` file. I think for some reason it is not regenerating.

Comment: @drescherjm, added .h

Comment: I mean the generated header that is produced by `uic` which in your case is `ui_mainwindow.h`

Comment: What does your PRO file look like?  Does it have something like `FORMS = mainwindow.ui` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMainWindows can be tricky. You need to set your central widget explicitly:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(ui->centralWidget);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->succ->setText("yeah");
    ui->help_plz->setText("xxx"); //no member named "help_plz" in UI::MainWindow
}
```

This should compile (though I doubt it does what you want). FWIW: note that this exercise would have been more straightforward had you used QWidget instead of QMainWindow as your UI.

Comment: Are you Jesus? I created a new project using QWidget and it works flawlessly. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Haha...no, not Jesus...just someone who's made lots of Qt mistakes in his day. There's a time and place for both Widgets and MainWindows; the salient difference is how much "environment" you want/need around your UI. Hard to say which is best for yours, given that your source code was (mercifully) brief.

Answer (score 1):

It says `no member named "textEdit" in UI::MainWindow` because there isn't anything called `textEdit` in your `.ui` file (you can search it yourself to confirm it). You cannot access UI elements that are not there. Add a line edit to your ui file.

Comment: I've got a QLineEdit named "help_plz" (that's like 3 time I re-upload this question to make people see it, sorry, I've changed question description)